# Get a table cell when a gesture fires

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that I defined in a storyboard. I added a gesture to an image within the table cell. I capture the gesture just fine and change the image.

What I need to do now is remove the tableCell from the table list, but I'm having trouble finding a reference to that table cell.

How do I get the table cell indexPath or a reference to that table cell? I don't really want to climb the superview later as it seems to me there must be an easier/better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution. Using target action I did this.

```
-(void)checkMarkTapDetected:(id)sender {
// Update the image
UIImageView *checkMarkImage = (UIImageView *)[sender view];
checkMarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"];

// Get recognizer and the place it fired in the tableview
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[checkMarkImage gestureRecognizers] lastObject];
CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

// Get table cell index based on gesture location in table view cell
_checkMarkRowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
}
```

Comment: Thanks :). I like to spend the time to think of more elegant solutions than just hammer something threw that works but isn't as functional. Hope this helps someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options. You can use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: or you can send reloadData to your tableView. reloadData will cause your delegate method cellforRowAtIndexPath (and related methods) to be called again but this time you will not create that very cell. Your numberOfRowsInSection will have to reflect the decrease of rows too.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question a little. It may have been the way I worded it. I was looking for cell reference to actually call the delete methods for table view. I actually figured out a solution and will post in a new message.